# Mudar visualização quando clicar sobre outro item?

Tags: javascript, email, front-end, vue.js, click

Estou fazendo uma aplicação de emails e quero que quando eu clicar o email que está sendo visualizado mude.

[image: Front-end da aplicação de email]

O que eu quero que aconteça é:

Eu quero aplicar a mesma função nas duas partes. Quanto à clicar no email, se eu clicar no *remetente2* quero que ele apareça na área de visualização, se eu clicar em outro, quero que esse outro seja mostrado... Sem recarregar a página.

É viável fazer essas funções??

Comment: Não deu para compreender o que você quis dizer com *Quando eu clicar no remetente2, eu possa visualizar o email clicado na metade à direita da tela, e o mesmo vale para o menu de bem à esquerda,*

Comment: Eu quero aplicar a mesma função nas duas partes. Quanto à clicar no email, se eu clicar no remetente2, quero que ele apareça na área de visualização, se eu clicar em outro, quero que esse outro seja mosrado

Comment: Você já escreveu o código? Em qual parte do seu código você está com dificuldade? Cadê a função? Poste a parte interessante à pergunta do seu código para podermos lhe ajudar da melhor forma possível.

Comment: basta fazeres uma função como `mudarView(ID da mensagem)` e depois na div ao lado removes tudo o que tens la dentro e fazes requisição a base de dados com id da mensagem e baste imprimir de novo

Comment: Interface bonita, essa UI  é do próprio framework Vue.js?
@LeonardoEbert

Comment: @Godfrey the King, eu ainda não escrevi o código, apenas quero saber se vou ter que utilizar os manipuladores de eventos de Vue ou outros recursos

Comment: UI do vue.js ? whatt essa é nova para mim

Comment: Você pode utilizar os manipuladores de evento sim. Agora tenho que concordar... Que interface maravilhosa! Parabéns.

Comment: @Diogo, essa interface eu criei usando o Quasar Framework, é muito bom e fácil de usar, recomendo você dar uma olhada na documentação(muito boa e grande), pois dá para fazer muita coisa com o Quasar.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Godfrey

Comment: @13dev, vou tentar com essa função que você mencionou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certo, faça uma função que recebe o ID do email

Essa função será responsável por quando acionada buscar as informações do email clicado e preencher o campo da direta.

Deu pra entender a lógica?

Comment: Isso funcionará para qualquer email clicado na lista

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado @Pedro Soares